# VoIP integration / architecture for a WEB app (Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asterisk, sip, voip

I want to understand how can I integrate VoIP for my WEB app which in my case would be a Rails app.

What I wan't to achieve is sending socket events to the front-end for each call state:

- call ringing
- call started
- call ended

The implementation is already done but I'm not convinced if is the right architecture and the informations I found until now over the internet are poor.

I don't think that makes sense to explain how is currently done (but if needed I can provide), but starting from `ruby-asterisk` gem which can be used to retrieve data about an extension number what would be the correct architecture in order to retrieve continuously events from call states and send them as socket events to the WEB?

How can you determine if the call is ended?

On the overall implementation, do you see any use of redis for saving previous states of a call and then to determine the new states?

Answer (score 1):

Main issue is : **asterisk is PBX**

Again: it is small office PBX, not all-in-one platform with API.

So correct architecture for high load is centralized hi-perfomance socket server, which support auth, response on your api calls(if any), event notification etc etc. After that you have use AMI+ dialplan to notify you server about actions on PBX.

You web app should connect to thoose server, not directly to asterisk. Only ONE connection to asterisk recommended for peformance considerations.

If you have low load - doesn't matter what you do, it likly will work ok.

Asterisk not support redis, so use of that unlikly. Use CDRs for end event.

Comment: This site is not right place to get consultation about how to write programms, sorry. We only answer EXACT questions.